# Convert a hexadecimal value into a binary value

Tags: c++

I have a program that needs to take a hexadecimal value of 2 digits (up to `FF`)  and convert each digit into a separate 4-digit binary value (up to `1111`). I'm able to write an algorithm that would do this for me, but before I do that, is there an easy way to do this with built-in functions in C++?

Comment: Are doing this with string representations of hexadecimal characters? What is the type of `FF`

Comment: You can perhaps check if the below answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310952/convert-strings-between-hex-format-and-binary-format

Answer (score 0):

Write a mapping between the hex charachters an their binary.

```
std::string HexCharToBinary( char c ) {
switch (c) {
  case '0': return "0000";
  case '1': return "0001";
  // Now input rest of the cases.
  case 'f': return "1111";
  default: assert(false); return "bad input";
};
```

As pointed out @Crazy Eddie in comment section.

Using an array would much better and optimal solution.

Comment: Can you please link this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483609/how-can-i-convert-hexadecimal-numbers-to-binary-in-c) instead, to avoid duplication.

Comment: Why oh why didn't you just use an array???

Comment: If an answer to another question answers this, mark the question as duplicate rather than copy the answer. Definitely don't copy without attribution.

Comment: @CrazyEddie : My bad. I didn't thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question that was already answered here:

[Convert strings between hex format and binary format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310952/convert-strings-between-hex-format-and-binary-format)

You might want to check it out, I think the answer provided there is complete and easy to understand.